# Run macro on all files open in taskbar one by one

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

My work is regarding formating 100 of files everyday. though i have a macro desined for the purpose but i have to run the macro on each and every file one after saving previous.

my question is how can i be able to run my macro on these opened workbooks in one step. As i save one it would run on other one in the queue.

Comment: You can use something like `Workbooks.Open` to open a workbook from a "base" workbook and manipulate its content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got my solve using below code.

```
Sub OpenAllWorkbooksnew()
        Set destWB = ActiveWorkbook
        Dim DestCell As Range

        Dim cwb As Workbook
        For Each cwb In Workbooks

            **Call donemovementReport**
            ActiveWorkbook.Close True
            ActiveWorkbook.Close False
        Next cwb
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the following macro in a "BASE" workbook as [Passerby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/570812/passerby) mentioned

```
Sub SO()
    Dim macroList As Object
    Dim workbookName As String
    Dim wbFullPath
    Dim macroName As String
    Dim currentWb As Workbook
    Dim masterWb As Workbook ' the Excel file you are calling this procedure from
    Dim useWbList As Boolean
    Dim height As Long, i As Long
    Dim dataArray As Variant
    useWbList = False  ' DEFINE which input method
    Set macroList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    If useWbList Then
        ' you can also from the dictionary from 2 columns of an excel file , probably better for management
        With masterWb.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<~~ change Sheet1 to the sheet name storing the data
            height = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' Assume data in column A,B, starting from row 1
            If height > 1 Then
                ReDim dataArray(1 To height, 1 To 2)
                dataArray = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(height, 2)).Value
                For i = 1 To height
                    macroList.Add dataArray(i, 1), dataArray(i, 2)
                Next i
            Else
                'height = 1 case
                macroList.Add .Cells(1, 1).Value, .Cells(1, 2).Value
            End If
        End With
    Else
        ' ENTER THE FULl PATH in 1st agrument below,       Macro Name in 2nd argument
        ' Remember to make sure the macro is PUBLIC, try to put them in Module inside of Sheets'

        macroList.Add "C:\Users\wangCL\Desktop\Book1.xlsm", "ThisWorkbook.testing"
        'macroList.Add "FULL PATH", "MACRO NAME"
        'macroList.Add "FULL PATH", "MACRO NAME"
        'macroList.Add "FULL PATH", "MACRO NAME"
    End If

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For Each wbFullPath In macroList.keys
        On Error GoTo 0
        macroName = macroList.Item(workbookName)
        workbookName = Mid(wbFullPath, InStrRev(wbFullPath, "\") + 1)
        Err.Clear
        On Error Resume Next
        Set currentWb = Nothing
        Set currentWb = Workbooks(workbookName) ' see if the workbook is already open

        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            ' open the workbook if workbook NOT opened
            Set currentWb = Workbooks.Open(workbookName, ReadOnly:=True)
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

        ' run the macro
        Application.Run workbookName & "!" & macroList.Item(wbFullPath)


        'close the workbook after running the macro
        currentWb.Close saveChanges:=False
        Set currentWb = Nothing
    Next wbFullPath
End Sub
```

Hope it helps and please let me know if there's anything unclear

Comment: That code looks good. For ease of use, I would create the macrolist from a dedicated "master" excel file.
Also, I would not simply resume work if I encounter an error, but write some kind of warning, so you do not have to check every workbook for errors.

Comment: i am failing at the step where i have to define my macros name?

Comment: @user1960257 For testing purpose, you can simply replace my line `macroList.Add "C:\Users\wangCL\Desktop\Book1.xlsm", "ThisWorkbook.testing"`   to your own line,  the 2nd argument is the macro name

Comment: which file will book1 replace from my system?

Comment: @user1960257 um. how about this, can you list a few full_path of the excel you need to run macro from, and the macro name as well? so i can put them in my solution for your reference    ________________   Book1 is a example file with macro I make up..

Comment: i have to run my macro on more than 200 files existing in one folder. and the macro which i want to run on these files is in module1 in personal sheet i dont where its located in my system. whenever i try open it i use developer tool. ]

Comment: Sorry I'm not understanding your question completely. Would someone help to clarify?